# What role does 'something' have?

Tags: relative-clauses

> The rest of the team hung back to talk to one another as usual at the end of practice, but Harry headed straight back to the Gryffindor common room, where he found Ron and Hermione playing chess. Chess was the only thing Hermione ever lost at, **something** Harry and Ron thought was very good for her. 
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

‘Something’ looks alike to complementizers, for example ‘that’ or ‘what’ or ‘which’. But I can’t find this usage in dictionaries. What role does ‘something’ take in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *something* in this case refers to *losing*. The sentence could be rewritten as:

> *Chess was the only thing Hermione ever lost at, and Harry and Ron thought it was very good for her to lose at something.*

Comment: So 'something' refers to 'Hermione's losing'and takes the subject role in 'was very good for her' Isn't it?

Comment: or form "something (=very important thing) that was very good for her" 'that' is omitted.

Comment: Yes, I suppose you could parse it that way.

Comment: Which one do you say, the first or the second?

Comment: I was referring to the first (we were typing at the same time), but the second isn't too bad, either.